# Are there any easter eggs related to the Calendar Man?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Does the Calendar Man say or do anything special on certain holidays?

Comment: @Cyberskull While I admire your editing ambition, can you please run it by the community by either coming into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) or [making a meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) before creating new tags like `holidays`? The use of such classification tags is [debated](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/whats-going-on-with-meta-tags), so running it by the community first seems prudent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If you talk to him on the holidays for your region of the game he will have special things to say. The achievement for doing so is the [Storyteller](http://www.trueachievements.com/a155697/storyteller-achievement.htm) achievement. The Sionis Industries calendar next to his cell (also a Riddler puzzle solution) will have the dates circled. After speaking to him and reloading the area, the month will be marked off on the calendar. The first one to come up is Halloween on October 31<sup>st</sup>.

[[image: Storyteller]
Storyteller](http://www.trueachievements.com/a155697/storyteller-achievement.htm)

Comment: Mark your calendars! Or you know, change the system time on your machine.

Comment: Oh brother...I was worried that the achievement would be something like this. Guess I'm going with the system time change route then.

Comment: @Kotsu Same here. I waited for the You Don't Know Jack 4th of July one because it was kind of funny. But not sure I'd be able to hit 12 times over a year.